# How to compress unique ID of object into 96 bit memory of RFID

Tags: python, text, encoding, compression, rfid

RFID Technology in some countries is expensive and restriction is to have data stored in 96 bit memory tag. The system that I am using has 24 character code that conforms to type of packaging/contents and since its 128 bits it is expensive from memory standpoint.

Therefore, I would like to write a program in Python so that I can compress the same 24 code to 96 bits. If any other software like C can help please let me know. I should also have the capability to read it back and re-transform it.

A sample identification code is M1P100000812341567678991

## Code

```
import zlib
import bz2
a = 'M1P100000812341567678991'
b = a.encode()
c = zlib.compress(b, level=9)
```

Thank You.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: I have used Zlib function in Python but I think when you measure bits the output is definitely more than 96 bits.

Comment: Is it just the first 3 chars which could be alphabetic and the rest numeric?

Comment: Perhaps. What are your thoughts? The issue is every ID is unique else I could split common components and join them back again after reading from RFID.

Comment: E.G. you can assign 4 bytes to the block which includes the M1P1 part and the remaining 8 bytes to a pure number. That 8 bytes gives you a larger max number than the 20 digits in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 96 bits, that is 12 bytes. If the first three characters of your ID are alphabetic, then they will fit into the first three bytes. The rest, if taken as a binary number, should fit into 9 bytes:

```
a = 'M1P990000812341567678991'
head = a[:3]
tail = a[3:]
head = head.encode('utf-8')
tail = int(tail).to_bytes(9, byteorder='little')
print(head.hex())
print(tail.hex())
```

Output (in hex, but the two byte arrays are really 3 and 9 bytes in length)

```
4d3150
0fea4b57936d05ab35
```

Comment: Thanks but however if you use sys function and use command sys.getsizeof(head.hex()) this gives 55 and sys.getsizeof(tail.hex()) give 67. Combining these two is 122 bytes. I may be wrong but I appreciate your help and efforts helping out.

Comment: No, I mean len(head) == 3 and len(tail) == 9, so the information can be sent over a wire or stored in the eeprom of an RFID card in 12 bytes.

Comment: This helps. Would you then please tell me difference between sys getsize of and Len function?

Comment: `sys.getsizeof()` takes into account all the memory requirements for the type to store all of the underlying data, including as yet unused memory allocations. `len()` is simply the number of elements. In the case of `len(head)` that is 3, which is 3 bytes which is 24 bits.

Comment: Your edit makes no sense. What is `b` in `binascii.hexlify(b)`?

Comment: I am sorry it should be s. Typo while editing in SO

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212193/discussion-between-sid1980-and-quamrana).